# Parse token from a file in c++

Tags: c++, token

//  How we can handle Acronyms(e.g  "U.S" "U.N") while parsing tokens from a file. I have used strtok to parse tokens and it separates U & S from "U.S". Below code I am using to parse tokens from every line I read from file. I convert token into lower case and stores in a map. Thanks in advance.

```
char *pch = strtok (text," ,.-()/{}[]*&#");
    while (pch != NULL)
    {
       for (char *iter = pch; *iter != '\0'; iter++)
       {
            *iter = tolower(*iter);
       }
         string str(pch);
         token_list.insert(pair<T,K>(str,fileName));//stores token with filename in which it is found
         word_count[str]++;//stores token with its frequency
         pch = strtok(NULL," ,.-()/{}[]*&#");
    }
```

Comment: Is there any way I can handle acronyms even without using strtok ? reply is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is to make another function to add spaces in front and behind the words you are trying to seperate, like U.S to (space)U.S(space). Then you just parse the string for spaces instead.